# How do you adjust overlay layer on scroll with Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, maps

I can't figure out how to get the overlay layer from Google Maps to adjust itself when the map is scrolled.

I'm doing something like

```
div = document.createElement('div')
div.style.position = 'absolute';
div.borderColor = "red";
this.getPanes().overlayLayer.appendChild(div)
```

And when I scroll the map around I see the red box of my div in the overlay where the original border of the map was. Everything inside there is fine, but what if there is new content outside that overlay layer once I scroll? It would be nice if I could get the overlay layer to adjust itself every time the bounds, zoom etc. Changed but I can't see how.

Answer (score 0):

One way around this is to adjust the position of whatever child you attached to the overlayLayer. I can trigger a draw on 'bounds_changed' or some such event and then in the draw method (assuming @div is the child of the overlay):

```
bounds = @getMap().getBounds()
sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(bounds.getSouthWest());
ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(bounds.getNorthEast());
@div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
@div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
@div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
@div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
```

I guess that's not bad, but then you have to constantly be considerate of the offsets and it doesn't seem so clean. I suppose this will do, but hoped that there was a better way to have the actual overlayLayer move to match the map's window instead of staying fixed on the initial viewport.